# Ajax Request Div Without Page Reload

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery-ajax

I have this `<div>` element that changes randomly. Sometimes, for example, it is like this:

```
<td class="Disabled activeClass" title="disable"></td>
```

And sometimes it is like this:

```
<td class="Enabled activeClass" title="Enable"></td>
```

Can I do an Ajax request every 15 minutes, for example, to alert me if the element changes without reloading the whole page?

This is what I tried:

```
  $.ajax({
     type: 'POST',
     data: 'gofor="Enabled activeClass',    
     url: 'ajax.php',
     success: function(response) {  
        ClassName("Enabled activeClass").html(response);
     }
  });
```

I'm kinda new to this stuff so take it easy on me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming this is the problem you are trying to solve:

- You want a way to be able to know and react to a change to an element on your page.

And you are asking:

- Can I make an Ajax request from a page, to observe if an element on that same page has changed.

If that is correct, then the answer to your question is **No**.

Ajax request is for backend calls. You cannot make an Ajax call to fetch the page that the Ajax call is being called from, and get it to observe changes to it. Your Ajax request may be able to fetch the same page, but it will be a fresh copy of that page from your server, and not the instance of the page that the browser is currently displaying.

Instead, to observe changes to specific elements of the DOM (current page) and be able to react to that change, you need to use a [`MutationObserver`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver/MutationObserver). It does exactly what its name says: observe a change to a DOM element.

In order to do that:

- Define the target of the `MutationObserver`

```
const targetNode = document.querySelector('div.active');
```

- Define the options for the `MutationObserver`. This describes what the observer should observe. In this case, we want to

```
const observerOptions = {
  // Observe only the "class" attribute
  attributeFilter: ['class'],
  // Record the previous value of the "class" attribute 
  // so we can show on the console log
  attributeOldValue: true,
  // Observe only the target node 
  // and ignore changes to children nodes of the target node.
  subtree: false
}
```

- Create the callback function for the `MutationObserver`. This function is called by the observer when it observes a change to the target.

```
function mutationCallback(mutationList, observer) {
   // TODO: Implement this
}
```

- Create the `MutationObserver`, passing the callback function.

```
const observer = new MutationObserver(mutationCallback);
```

- Start observing, passing the target and the options.

```
observer.observe(targetNode, observerOptions);
```

- At some point when you want to stop the observing changes to the target, you can disconnect the observer.

```
observer.disconnect();
```

**EXAMPLE**

Below is an example where a `div` is being updated when you click a `button`. When the `button` is clicked, it calls `toggleDiv()` which changes the `div`'s *class* and *title* attributes, and the text inside the `div`.

Then I created a `MutationObserver` to independently check for changes to the *class* attribute of the `div`. This observer only observes *class* attribute changes on the `div`. Upon observing a change, it calls the callback function `mutationCallback()`.

```js
function toggleDiv() {
  const el = document.querySelector('div.active');
  const isDisabled = el.classList.contains('disabled');
  if (isDisabled) {
    el.classList.replace('disabled', 'enabled');
    el.setAttribute('title', 'enabled');
    el.innerText = 'Enabled';
  } else {
    el.classList.replace('enabled', 'disabled');
    el.setAttribute('title', 'disabled');
    el.innerText = 'Disabled';
  }
}

function mutationCallback(mutationList, observer) {
  mutationList.forEach((mutation) => {
    if (mutation.type === 'attributes') {
      console.log(`The ${mutation.attributeName} attribute has changed from '${mutation.oldValue}' to '${mutation.target.classList}'`);
    }
  });
}

const targetNode = document.querySelector('div.active');
const observerOptions = {
  // Observe only the "class" attribute
  attributeFilter: ['class'],
  // Record the previous value of the "class" attribute
  attributeOldValue: true,
  // Observe only the target node. Ignore changes to children nodes of the target node.
  subtree: false
}

const observer = new MutationObserver(mutationCallback);
observer.observe(targetNode, observerOptions);
```

```html
<div class="disabled active" title="disabled">Disabled</div>
<br/>
<button onclick="toggleDiv()">Toggle div</button>
```

Comment: Bro thank you so much for making it easy on me to understand i appreciate your help